# Add a new field by applying a regex with Logstash

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I want to add a new field by applying a regex on a field named "referer". So the objectif is to have a new field based on the regex match !
This is an example of my referers :

```
http://staticftv-a.akamaihd.net/player/bower_components/player_flash/dist/FranceTVNVPVFlashPlayer.akamai-05bcfb8a5a233afa06de66e8c03d6642.swf
```

I want to have a new field with only **staticftv-a.akamaihd.net**

This is my logstash conf :

```
input {

    file {
            path => "/home/ec2-user/AggregateByReferer.csv"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}

filter {

    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ['session_number', 'referer', 'request_number_total']
    }


    grok { 

       match => { "message" => "%{URI:referer}" }

    }


}


output {

    elasticsearch {

    index => "referer"

    }
}
```

With this code, the field "message" give me a strange content. This is the resulat in Kibana :

[image]

What to do ? thx !

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the `regex` pattern as such in my *pattern* file :

```
URI (\/)[^\/\+]+
```

which actually gives the value as `/staticftv-a.akamaihd.net`.

You could use it in your **grok** filter as:

```
grok {    
    match => { 
       "message" => "%{URI:referer}"   <-- the value looks like /staticftv-a.akamaihd.net
    }    
}
```

In order to remove that extra forward slash, you could use **gsub**:

```
mutate {
    gsub => [ 
        "referer", "/", "",
    ]
}
```

And then you could simply overwrite the existing message with the new value:

```
grok {    
    match => { 
       overwrite => ["message"]
    }    
}
```

The [grok debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/). I'm not sure if this is an effective way of extracting the required value above. But hope this helps!